# Android - Show hidden views according to secondsDelayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am trying to show invisible ImageViews on OnCreate method. I have a bunch of ImageViews that creates a tree image (E.g. ivStem, ivRoot... etc). These ImageViews are invisible at first, but after a few second, one will show up, another one again, and again... But the problem is I am having a hard time how to do it. I've tried the code below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    ImageView ivLogoText = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLogoText);
    final double secondsDelayed = 5;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeLeftPanel.class));

            //What should I put here?
            if (secondsDelayed == 2000) {
                ivLogoText.setVisibility(1);
            } ...//more if statement here

            finish();
        }
    }, (long) (secondsDelayed * 1000));
```

Overall, I have 5 seconds delayed. What I want to happen is set the visibility of this ImageViews according to that delay. How can I do this? I believed this is just an easy question but I've been searching for an hour and still can't find solutions. Thanks in advanced!